# How to make a mirrored bar chart with amCharts5 XY column series stacked series

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, amcharts5

I need a bar chart that comparatively displays two sets of data side by side along a horizontal axis.

So I have a stacked (but not clustered) column series XY chart (amCharts 5) which looks like this:

[image]

The plotted data is coming from an array of objects:

```
[
 {
  current: 61,
  previous: 29,
  ...
 },
 {
  current: 60,
  previous: 29,
  ...
 },
...
]
```

Now, how can I achieve this:

[image]

Do I need to find the average between `current` and `previous` then set that as a base, or do I really need negative values (say for previous) to achieve that? Either way, I was unable to make it look like above.

[Found an example with amCharts4](https://codepen.io/arseniy-kushnir/pen/GRjJwYa?editors=0010) but I don't understand how should I modify my chart to achieve the same mirror bar chart look.

I've put the chart together in a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-hertz-z2xw4z) playground, I would appreciate some help. Data is hardcoded and there's an object with `previous` negative values aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, you need two vertical axes with opposite directions. They could be configured like so:

```js
let yAxisCurrent = chart.yAxes.push(
  am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {}),
    calculateTotals: true,
    visible: true,
    min: 0
  })
);
  
let yAxisPrevious = chart.yAxes.push(
  am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
      inversed: true // <--- DO NOT FORGET THIS
    }),
    calculateTotals: true,
    visible: true,
    min: 0
  })
);
```

Then add this line of code:

```js
chart.leftAxesContainer.set("layout", root.verticalLayout);
```

Here is the result: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-hooks-vwucth

Comment: Briliant, thank you very much, I finally get it! Would you mind using this updated playground link so other fellow devs could benefit from your answer, instead of directly exposing the object structure, as I did not really want to do that.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-hooks-vwucth

Or just obfuscate the key names from the objects, e.g. curr, prev, currFromDate, etc.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want me to remove the snippet from Stack Overflow and put this link instead? I do not see any update in your CodeSandbox, by the way. :)

Comment: Yes, please, if you won't mind, or just rename the object keys. Damn, forgot to save it, it's working now!

Comment: OK, no problem. I see the updates now in your CodeSandbox. ;)